# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'customize type'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm now learning angular with Angular official website's tutorial.

I don't know how to add string variable into Hero[](which is my customize type)

**heroes.component.ts**

```js
import { Hero } from '../hero';

heroes: Hero[];

test(heroname: string) {
    // this.heroes.id = 1;
    if (heroname) {
        console.log(heroname);
        this.heroes.push(heroname);
    }
}
```

**heroes.component.html**

```html
<form>
    <label>name:
    <input #hero placeholder="name">
  </label>
  <button (click)="test(hero.value); hero.value=''" >test</button>
  <label *ngFor ="let heroh of heroes">
      <p>hero: {{heroh}}</p>
  </label>
</form>
```

**hero.ts**

```js
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can push into `heroes` array just `hero` objects.

hero object should look like this `{id: 1, name: 'heroName'})`

And you should initialize a value for the array like this:

```
  heroes: Hero[] = [];
```

Comment: Glad to help :) kann you accept it as answer please? :)

Comment: It does mean that you accepted my answer :)
somebody has down rated my answer for some reason, which I don't understand :/

Comment: I think that's my problem... too simple problem to learn things but wasting their time haha ~

Answer (score 0):

```
this.heroes.push({id: 1, name: heroname});
```

You should also initialise `heroes` array:

```
heroes: Hero[] = [];
```

Comment: Thanks but it's still wrong with "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Comment: @KevinLee add `heroes: Hero[] = [];` :)

Comment: then intialise the heroes with an empty array

Answer (score 0):

change it into **interface**

```
 export interface hero 
{

id:number;
name:string;
}
```

As u used HERO[] type interface for ur variable heros;
it will be accepting a object with combination of id and name;

so u should push 
this.heroes.push({id:1,name:heroname})

Comment: Thanks but it's still wrong with "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Comment: can u get with stackblitz;

Comment: You need to initialize your array to `[]` or it will be `undefined`.

Comment: haven't used that before, but I know the problem now. Thanks